# the blank final field may not have been initialized

Tags: java, final

PS: There are questions with similar topic but what I am asking is essentially different.

I understand the reason behind the error

> the blank final field may not have been initialized

when I try to do something like

```
  final Object[] items;
```

But what concerns me is the JDK ArrayBlockingQueue implementation [HERE](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue). How is that same line (line #87) is getting used here with no errors ?

Comment: Yes, but have you seen [the constructors](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.java#ArrayBlockingQueue.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the fields are initialized in the constructor

```
  public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair) {
        if (capacity <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.items = new Object[capacity];
        lock = new ReentrantLock(fair);
        notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
        notFull =  lock.newCondition();
    }
```